# Connect VGA cooling fan (12vdc - 0.1A) to constant current driver (120Vac to 12- 22vdc @ 0.3A)

Tags: led-driver, constant-current, cob

I have an AC driven COB LED which can be connected directly to the AC main in house (120v). I would like to attach a cooling fan to the COB which requires 12vdc @ 0.1A. I have a constant current driver which converts 120VAC to 12- 22Vdc @ 0.3amp.
Is it possible to use this driver to power the cooling fan at the 0.1A rating by using a resistor?

I am assuming the power supply would increase the voltage to get the current to 0.3a, therefore I do not know if this is possible, or what voltage value to use to calculate resistance needed.

Comment: Buy a $3, 19V, 180lm/W, Bridgelux BXEB-L0280Z-50E1000-C-B3 strip that will not need a heatsink or fan and you can toss the CoB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hooked the fan directly to the constant-current driver, it would raise the voltage until it got to its compliance limit (22 V), which would seriously overpower the fan. What can you do with resistors?

- You could use a series resistor as a voltage dropper. It would have to be (22 V - 12 V) / 0.1 A = 100 Ω, and will be dissipating 1 W. This works as long as the 22 V is a fairly firm limit — it may or may not be.
- You could use a shunt resistor to bypass the excess current. It would have to be 12 V / 0.2 A = 60 Ω, dissipating 2.4 W.

Neither of these seems particularly desirable. Get a 12 V power supply for the fan.

Comment: Does a series resistor act as a voltage dropper when the current is constant?  If the current remains the same and the fan's DC resistance remains the same, why would  the fan's voltage not be the same?

Comment: @Misunderstood: The current is no longer constant when the current source reaches its voltage compliance limit. We are using the resistor to force it there while still maintaining the nominal voltage across the fan.

Comment: " with a power rating of 1 W." Note that the 100 ohm series resistor will dissipate 1 watt. This is not the same as saying the resistor should have a 1 watt rating. 1 watt mimimum, OK, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: OK, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A 12V zener diode across the fan would hold the terminal voltage at a value appropriate for the fan, and pass whatever current the fan didn't from the constant current source. Something like [1N5349BRLG](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N5333B-D.PDF) would do it.
 These fans are typically open loop, and will run faster if the voltage rises, but they're not critical of supply accuracy.
 Dissipation would be the difference between the supplied constant current, less the fan consumption, multiplied by the Zener voltage. A 5W looks to be needed for this.

Comment: You might want to comment on the required power rating of the zener. The particular zener you linked has a current limit of 208mA and a maximum zener voltage of 13.65V so I'm not sure that's such a good choice.

Comment: Agreed, my mental calculations got me to 2.4W, so a 3W should be OK, but it's probably not worth worrying about the extra couple of pennies for a larger one given the margin improvement.